# Duplicate domain names - .net and .com Create separate pages, or redirect?

Tags: domains, redirects, multiple-domains

In a SEO point of view:

This website has a good amount of traffic for a local business, but also ships some merchandise.
While the **.net domain (registered first)** is associated with the **local busines (google places, maps, etc...) the .com domain only redirects** to the .net domain.

Is it good, bad or okay to create a different page for the domain .com for example, that would be pretty simple, but would link to the 10 different categories of products that this company sells?

I know links are good, so there's that, but what else is good, or bad?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best to keep things as they are, unless you're making two entirely different websites. From a customer's point of view, it could just be confusing to see a .com and a .net of what appears to be the same company. There's also the consistency of branding to think about.

From an SEO point of view, you definitely want to avoid duplicate content. But is it really necessary to devote your time to this second site? What is it really supposed to accomplish?

If you're looking to create "mini sites" you're better off keeping the redirect and using subdomains on your main site.

Comment: What about creating the same exact front page. Maybe a different title. Would i possibly be hurting from dividing the traffic between the domains? I could be gaining from links. Remember, it's a local business, not a page with 100.000 links.